# Haneda airport by bicycle

Tags: airport-transfer, tokyo, bicycles, hnd

[Haneda airport](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo_Haneda_Airport) is situated on an island, close to the [Ota Ward](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo/Ota) center.

Can I go to the international terminal of Haneda airport by bicycle from the continent (and back)?

Is there a place where I can leave my bicycle for a few nights?

Google Maps can not always be trusted, but it proposes a walking route (meaning it might contain stairs and going through places forbidden to bicycles):

[image: map]

Comment: Why "close"? Haneda airport is located in Ota city (more usually called "Ota ward").

Answer (score 4):

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQgJCsTP5Pg) should help with a route. Looks like some sidewalk riding is required, but in an area you're unlikely to find that many pedestrians.

The comments there discuss parking a little bit (an anecdotal statement you could use the staff parking for a few hours), but [the official answer](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/access/) is that "there is no bicycle parking at the airport."

There is a [luggage storage service](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/delivery.html#temporary), but there are size and weight limits and "we may not accommodate your luggage because of a shape or content of the item." I'd contact them in advance. They may require your bike be disassembled and boxed, which would obviously present some complications.

Comment: It is worth adding that riding on the sidewalks is illegal..

Comment: @Rilakkuma It actually depends on the width of the sidewalk etc, and for what it's worth, the law is for all practical purposes not enforced.

Answer (score 3):

Well I tried to using google maps "pedestrian" path finding and failed.

For reference purpose both this ways are forbidden to bicycle:

[image]

I guess that leaves you with only one route.

Comment: That looks like Apple Maps, not Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If you have a chance to try the third option (Kanpachi-dori route), please let us know :-)

Comment: Unlikely it will come any time soon, due to the lack of long term parking, and relative distance from my home.  But I'll think about it.
@ZachLipton the screenshot is there for illustration purposes. My point remains the same.